# How to go about writing a social activity notification process c# or Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, database, social-networking

sorry if the title is a little ambiguous..

I am trying to work through ideas about how to update a database (or other storage options?) for when an activity is performed.  Let me explain a bit more based on a social network example:

1. You have say 100 members connected to you i.e. friends
2. You are going to add an activity, say an event to a database
3. You need to update your 100 connected members to ensure they know about this update.

So the idea so far was to write an item for the actual activity of course, then write an activity record.. i.e. member x has just created a new event (sort of like in facebook's api).
The idea then is to either:

a. Go and update the 100 members activity list with the ID say of the activity record/item.
   So essentially having to loop through 100 member records to add this activity item
b. Write the activity once, then as your 100 members access the system, they check the
   activity table/store for any new activities since last logged in.. however they only
   want to get their activities, not everyone's (although that's an option for later)

I am currently using MS-SQL as a "main" backend DB and currently experimenting with Couchbase for the caching etc.

I know this is a bit brief and can be interpreted in many ways, however because this is an experimental approach, I just want to get some varied ideas of how to move forward.

I have read a little about Neo4j graph database, and sounds interesting, however just trying to figure out more about the structure/process at this time.

Thank you.